# SSIS: database xyz cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

In SSIS 2008, is there is way to design an SSIS package around the problem when an OLE DB data source returns an error like this "Database [xyz] cannot be opened.  It is in the middle of restore."?

I am hoping there is a way to design a loop into an SSIS 2008 package to trap this error, maybe wait 5 or 10 minutes for the source DB to finish restoring (from log shipping for example) and then try again - with a max retry limit built in.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you connect, don't connect to your database. Use master, say, in a different connection object.

Then, query the state column in [sys.databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx). If not 0, wait for a bit, try again.