# Database 'wss_content_1' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore

Tags: sql-server, database, database-restore, mirror

This is the scenario: 
I am testing redundancy and fail over in my dev machine by creating two SQL Servers.

I have created two SQL Servers. One with an extra instance:

```
-SQL1 : primary server
-SQL2 : mirror server
-SQL2\wtn : witness instance
```

First I made a full backup of the database and transaction log in my primary server, then I restored the database and transaction log file.

I used option "`Restore with no recovery`".

In the database node "restoring" is being shown. I believe this is normal when you would like to keep pulling data.

Then in the primary server, I tried to create mirroring on the database. After the wizard completed, I clicked on start Mirroring, but now I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while starting mirroring.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Alter failed for Database 'WSS_Content_1'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Database 'wss_content_1' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 927)
```

I see there is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236712/ssis-database-xyz-cannot-be-opened-it-is-in-the-middle-of-a-restore) here on stack overflow, but that does not have much information. I have been waiting more than 10 minutes.

**Update**

I am using SQL Enterprise 2016 by the way. Perhaps there is a difference in 2016 version.

I was watching this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_5l5sodIOU) and my steps were exactly as this guy's.

**Update 2:**

I followed this as well but did not help.

[How to: Prepare a Mirror Database for Mirroring (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189047(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Do you really understand what you try to accomplish? Execute command "RESTORE  Database WSS_Content_1 WITH RECOVERY".

Comment: Agree with @DenisRubashkin, what options did you restore with?

Comment: What makes you think that I don't understand what I am trying to accomplish? 

I am using option: "`restore with no recovery`". It seems that you don't understand my question. MIRRORING.

Comment: If you use mirroring you should have a working database (WITH RECOVERY) on the primary server and a database in the state to be able to restore transaction log backups on the slave one (WITH NO RECOVERY).

Comment: Yes, I have one working database with `recovery` mode to `full` in my primary server and one in mirror server with state no recovery